# JFreeChart PolarPlot X Axis

Tags: java, plot, charts, jfreechart, polar-coordinates

I've got a problem. There is something wrong with X-axis. Zero is not in the middle of the chart. There is everything fine with the chart, but number axis is signed improperly. I'm newbie to java and jFreeChart.

Now, it looks like this:
[image]

But, it should look like this:
[image]

How to change it? Part of the code, containing an issue is below:

```
private static JFreeChart createChart(XYDataset dataset) {
    NumberAxis numberAxis = new NumberAxis();
    numberAxis.setTickLabelsVisible(false);

    DefaultPolarItemRenderer renderer = new DefaultPolarItemRenderer();
    renderer.setShapesVisible(false);

    PolarPlot plot = new PolarPlot(dataset, numberAxis, renderer);
    plot.setCounterClockwise(true);
    plot.setAxisLocation(PolarAxisLocation.EAST_BELOW);
    plot.setAngleOffset(0);

    JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart(title, JFreeChart.DEFAULT_TITLE_FONT, plot, true);
    return chart;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question with a [mcve]; the range of `Math.cos()` looks OK to me.